# Symfony 5 login form with JWT authentication

Tags: symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

Symfony 5 login form with JWT authentication

Hello,

How can I implement Symfony 5 login form with JWT authentication please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please install `LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle` and follow the steps

https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/index.html

https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/2.x/Resources/doc/index.rst#getting-started